# Retrieve photos backed up from Android and transferred to another phone via SD card

Tags: data-recovery, photos

my old android died and I replaced it with a new different one.  my old phone came with an option to hide pictures so that I could keep some private.  now that I have the new phone I cannot see these pics in the backup or on my SD card which I transferred to my new phone. It was an option already on the phone not an app that I downloaded. can any help me recover my pics? I know the pics are still there in the backup and on the SD card because they were never deleted and by the size of space used on the card itself.

Can someone help me retrieve my pics?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the devices' names and Android versions, and relevant apps, if any?

Answer (score 0):

If you have hidden images through gallery app, their name is Changed to start with a "."
Download a file Explorer like Es-file Explorer. 
I'm menu - >tools->show hidden files. 
Then select those pics and batch rename them. 
If the name is " .name.jpg"  change them to name.jpg
Hope that helps.